Що означає приросток па-?
Маємо багато слів з приростком па-, що він означає?

Стикнувся на Словотворі з пропоновую перекладу слова фалоімітатор -- папрутень. І звідти знайшов цікаві посилання, що містять відповідь на це запитання.

Горпинич В.О., Сучасна українська літературна мова, 1999.


Найдавніші іменні (ка-, па-, пра-, су-, у-):

виникли в праслов’янський (ранній) період; усі інші виникли пізніше — у конкретних слов’янських мовах, у тому числі і в українській;
мали деяку продуктивність;
були наголошені;
найдавніші іменні впродовж своєї історії втрачали продуктивність, витіснялися уживанішими (із-, под-, от-, прі-)\
найбільше залишилося слів з префіксами су-, па-, вони й зазнали найсуттєвіших змін.



Префікс па- має значення:

схожий на предмет, названий радиксоїдом: пагорб (схожий на горб, але похилий), паділ (невелика долина), пазелень (молода зелень), пагілля (молоде гілля);
вторинний стосовно предмета, названого радиксоїдом: парій (друге покоління рою бджіл в одне літо), пасмуиі, памолодь, павітер (слабкий вітер). Точніше його значення можна визначити як неповний вияв змісту, вказаного радиксоїдом: пагін, пагорок, пагуба, падчерка, паморозь, парость, пасинок, паводок, паволок, пасерб, парубок, пасіка, патока і под. У багатьох словах префікс па- можна виділити лише етимологічно.



Вад. Г. Скляренко, Префікс па- в українській мові, Культура мови.


Значна частина українських дериватів з префіксом па- з другим членом віддієслівного походження (хоча спочатку основою утворень були імена) виникла ще в праслов’янський період. Це такі слова, як па́губа, па́морока, па́стка, па́тока, па́толоч, па́вороз (Гр.), па́рубок (діал. па́робок). Дієслівна мотивація переважної їх більшості не викликає сумнівів (*paguba < *pogubiti «стратити, знищити», *pašeka < *pošekti «посікти, вирубати», *patoka < *potekti «потекти» і т. п.). Префікс не надає утворенням нового значення, а є немовби іменним відповідником дієслівного префікса по-, що виражає розширення дії, її початок чи закінчення тощо. Разом з іншими морфологічними рисами — суфіксацією, чергуванням, наголосом — він неначе сигналізує про приналежність деривата до класу імен.


Слід відзначити, що розрізнення двох представлених типів дериватів не завжди можливе у зв’язку з вторинними видозмінами мотивації окремих слів. Але головне полягає в тому, що в ранній період розвитку праслов’янської мови існували утворення з ра- (як першим компонентом) і з компонентом другим, мотивованим через дієслово. Етимологічний аналіз слів паву́к, мабуть, також па́пороть підказує, що спочатку це були утворення з *рō-(ра-), подовженого з невідмінюваної первісної форми прислівникового значення ро, з іменником віддієслівного походження. Близькі вони були до утворень типу па́горок, па́синок (див. далі) і різнилися лише мотивацією другого компонента (лише тому ми й розглядаємо їх разом з віддієслівними, а не з відіменними утвореннями). Перший же компонент виражав подібність до предмета, названого мотивуючим словом.


Далі словотворча модель розширювалась: іменники з префіксом па- почали утворюватись від дієслів з префіксом по- і стали означати результат дії основного дієслова: па́губа, па́морока, па́сіка, па́тока і т. д.


Крім віддієслівних дериватів з префіксом па-, в українській мові існують слова з тим же префіксом, мотивовані через імена. До найдавніших праслов’янських утворень належать па́нога «велика гілка, відгалуження» (Жел.), па́ріг «відросток, відгалуження рогів» (Жел.), па́рогач «олень» (Гр.), па́синок «нерідний син одного з подружжя, який доводиться рідним другому; бічний пагін рослини», па́дчерка «нерідна дочка одного з подружжя, яка доводиться рідною іншому; пасербиця», па́діл «невелика долина», па́горок «височина, часто з пологими схилами, пригір», па́луба «суцільне водонепроникне горизонтальне перекриття в корпусі або надбудова судна у вигляді підлоги; будка», па́кость «поганий, підступний, шкідливий учинок», паску́да «погана, мерзенна, підступна людина». Менш поширені в слов’янських мовах слова па́горб «пагорок» (зменш, па́горбок), па́смуга «смуга», па́кіл (діал.) «кілок» (зменш. па́колок, па́кілець), па́лука «лука» (Гр.).


У новіших утвореннях, де па- виражає вторинність, функція префікса випливає зі значення прийменника і ро «по, після», напр.: па́ріг, па́нога і т. д.


Окрему групу становлять значно новіші утворення з па-, мотивовані, як вважають окремі дослідники, через вирази з прийменником по: па́водок (< по воді), па́бородки «складки відвислої шкіри під бородою» (Гр.) па́бороди «бакенбари» (Жел.) (< по бороді). Не виключено, однак, що подібна мотивація витворилася вторинно.


Префікс па- і нині втратив продуктивність. У ході розвитку слов’янських мов він був
витіснений дієслівним префіксом по-.

